# getCsvControl() always returns same delimiter - PHP

Tags: php, csv, delimiter

```
    $file = new SplFileObject('D:\BackUp\addressbook.csv');
    print_r($file->getCsvControl());
```

What i am trying to do is find the delimiter of a csv file using php. the addressbook.csv file looks like

```
  "id";"firstname";"lastname";"phone";"email"
  "1";"jishan";"ishrak";"17878";"jishan.ishrak@gmail.com"
```

and another file is addressbook1.csv which is like

```
 "id","firstname","lastname","phone","email"
 "1","jishan","ishrak","17878","jishan.ishrak@gmail.com"
```

one is separated by "," and another one is with ";" but the function

```
  getCsvControl()
```

always returns an array like

```
 Array ( [0] => , [1] => " )
```

I mean in the [0] index it always gives "," for both files
is there a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Proabably this is a bug? 
as you can see here [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.getcsvcontrol.php) 1st comment 1 year ago - `Seems that this function always returns the same delimiter.`

**UPDATE**
this is not a bug look at `Pazi ツ` answer.

Comment: @jishan - this might help finding delimiter - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395267/how-to-find-out-if-csv-file-fields-are-tab-delimited-or-comma-delimited

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. `SplFileObject::getCsvControl()` is never intended to detect the delimiter from a CSV file. It returns only the default control characters or the one previously set with `SplFileObject::setCsvControl()`. And this set CSV control characters are used, if is nothing handed over in the `SplFileObject::fgetcsv()` method.

Ok, it's badly documented, but this were my first thoughts, the method would never detect the characters and a look into the php source code confirmed this.

Comment: in that case how can I find the delimiter from a csv file... @pazi

Comment: Look at the comment Peter gave in the other answer: "@jishan - this might help finding delimiter - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395267/how-to-find-out-if-csv-file-fields-are-tab-delimited-or-comma-delimited "