# Open CSV with comma or semicolon file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want open a file CSV with php but the input can be with comma or semicolon
how i can do that

i open the file with comma like that

```
if (($handle = fopen($filePath, 'r')) !== false) {
    // get the first row, which contains the column-titles (if necessary)
    $header = fgetcsv($handle);
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        var_dump($data);
      }
}
```

my file can be

```
   Test;option;money
   1;a;1,3
   2;"G;a";1,965,0
```

OR

```
   Test,option,money
   1,a,"1,3"
   2,"G;a",1,"965,0"
```

how i can test the separator to use fgetcsv ?

Comment: You can use the 3rd parameter of [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to specify a different separator, but you can only specify *one* at a time.

Comment: php's built in csv functions only support one delimeter at a time.

Comment: So what you do is read a line using comma as delimiter, and count  how many elements are in the array.  If only one, then close the file handle, reopen, etc. and read using semicolon as delimiter.

Comment: how i can test the file to use just right delimeter

Comment: [Maybe you'll find the answer in this StackOverflow article. There's an implementation proposal of a getFileDelimiter function.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395267/how-to-find-out-if-csv-file-fields-are-tab-delimited-or-comma-delimited)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can find the answer [in this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395267/how-to-find-out-if-csv-file-fields-are-tab-delimited-or-comma-delimited). It proposes an implementation for a delimiter detection method. The implementation is:

```
function getFileDelimiter($file, $checkLines = 2){
        $file = new SplFileObject($file);
        $delimiters = array(
          ',',
          '\t',
          ';',
          '|',
          ':'
        );
        $results = array();
        $i = 0;
         while($file->valid() && $i <= $checkLines){
            $line = $file->fgets();
            foreach ($delimiters as $delimiter){
                $regExp = '/['.$delimiter.']/';
                $fields = preg_split($regExp, $line);
                if(count($fields) > 1){
                    if(!empty($results[$delimiter])){
                        $results[$delimiter]++;
                    } else {
                        $results[$delimiter] = 1;
                    }   
                }
            }
           $i++;
        }
        $results = array_keys($results, max($results));
        return $results[0];
    }
```

Using that method you might end up with:

```
$delimiter = getFileDelimiter($filePath); // actual path of the file, ex: '../example.csv'

if (($handle = fopen($filePath, 'r')) !== false) {
    // get the first row, which contains the column-titles (if necessary)
    $header = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter);
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        var_dump($data);
      }
}
```

Comment: This is great idea!

Answer (score 1):

If the semi-colon and comma are used interchangeably, you would have to read the file in using one delimiter and then loop over each "column" and run that through `str_getcsv` to parse with the second delimeter. Something like this:

```
if (($handle = fopen($filePath, 'r')) !== false) {
    // get the first row, which contains the column-titles (if necessary)
    $header = fgetcsv($handle);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        //create empty array for this line
        $line = array();
        //loop over each "column" read in
        foreach($data as $d){
            //split using second delimeter and merge with line data
            $line = array_merge($line, str_getcsv($d, ';'));
        }
        //display the line
        print_r($line);
    }
}
```

Other than that, you would have to make/find your own csv parser that supports multiple delimeters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen($filePath, 'r')) !== false) {
    // Detect delimiter from first line.
    $delimiter = null;
    if ($firstLine = fgets($handle) !== false) {        
        if (strpos($firstLine, ",") !== false) {
            $delimiter = ",";
        } elseif (strpos($firstLine, ";") !== false) {
            $delimiter = ";"
        }
    }

    if (!is_null($delimiter)) {
        $isHeader = true;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
            if ($isHeader) {
                $isHeader = false;
                continue;
            }

            var_dump($data);
        }
    }
}
```

First try to detect delimiter from first line and than use it in parsing csv file.

Comment: What about this case: `Text Column1 ; 43,78 ; Text Column3`? Your code detects one comma and thinks the delimiter is a comma but is the semicolon.